# Can't get objectForKey from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using this code: https://github.com/valentinlietz/MySQL-Connect to use MySQL queries in objective c. I use Count(*) to check if this row already exists.

I used this code to NSLog(); this dictionary. Code:

```
for(NSArray *row in response.responseDictionary){

    NSLog(@"%@", row);

}
```

Result:

```
{
"" = "<null>";
"COUNT(*)" = 0;
}
```

But when I use `[response.responseDictionary objectForKey:@"COUNT(*)"];` It's returning Unrecognized selector sent to instance.

---

**Update:**

Row:

```
Row: ( { "" = "<null>"; "COUNT()" = 0; } )
```

Dictionary:

```
Row: { "" = "<null>"; "COUNT()" = 0; }
```

Comment: This implies that the object you're sending "objectForKey" is in fact not an NSDictionary. Please provide the actual code you used to call this method.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you are actually using?  If `response.responseDictionary` is a dictionary, then you would be looping over the keys in the dictionary.  You treat the keys as if they were arrays, and the debug output indicates that they are dictionaries.  This makes no sense.

Comment: [response.responseDictionary class] logs NSArray, but .responseDictionary implies that it's a NSDictionary right?

Comment: Something's not right here.  You give the above "Result:" listing (which appears to be an NSDictionary, though a strange one) as the apparent value of `row`, apparently an element of an NSArray, but then you toss `row` away (which was, BTW, misdeclared as an NSArray) and try to access the original object `response.responseDictionary` as if it were a dictionary.  I think you really need to step back and try to understand what you're doing.

Comment: I did try some different things and answered them on the different element. It is part of an NSArray, but if correct, the NSArray contained an NSDictionary, but I still can't get ObjectAtIndex. Also this is just a code sample from the library.

Comment: Please post the output from `NSLog(@"%@", response); NSLog(@"%@", response.responseDictionary);`

Comment: Response: <MySQLResponse: 0x1f818ea0>

Comment: Response.responseDictionary: {
    "" = "<null>";
    "COUNT(*)" = 0;
}

Comment: That last one is what you say is logged when you log *row*.  Which is the case?  They can't both be true.

Comment: 2013-05-12 16:51:18.427 HawQRate[8257:907] Row: (
        {
        "" = "<null>";
        "COUNT(*)" = 0;
    }
) - the response.response dictionary. - row: 2013-05-12 16:51:18.424 HawQRate[8257:907] Row: {
    "" = "<null>";
    "COUNT(*)" = 0;
}

Comment: It's really difficult to read things like that in comments.  Can you update your question with this information?

Comment: hi may be the space there in the key for value just print NSDictionay using NSLog then copy that key and use in your code

Comment: I'm sorry, you keep contradicting yourself.  I'd suggest you quit and start over from the beginning, making sure you ***understand*** what's going on at each step along the way, vs trying to make a "big leap" to the end.

Comment: Both your debug outputs are labelled "row".  Can you just use copy and paste instead of re-typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with that project, but from https://github.com/valentinlietz/MySQL-Connect/blob/master/MySQL.m it looks to me that `response.responseDictionary` is the result
of converting the JSON response of the script https://github.com/valentinlietz/MySQL-Connect/blob/master/mysql.php to a Foundation object.

And the code

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{ 
for($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
     $arr2[$fields[$i]] = $row[$fields[$i]]; 
}
 array_push($return_arr, $arr2);

}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

in that PHP script shows that the response is an *array of dictionaries*.

So if I am correct, the name and type of the `responseDictionary` property is badly chosen, because it is not an `NSDictionary`, but an `NSArray` where each object is an `NSDictionary`,
and the following should work:

```
NSArray *responseArray = (NSArray *)response.responseDictionary;
NSLog(@"count = %@", [[responseArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"COUNT(*)"]);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this works! Though responseArray already was a proper array.

Comment: @sjors: Perhaps you should try to contact the author of that package and tell him about this discrepancy. - Perhaps you should also check with `isKindOfClass` that this is really an array, to avoid crashes in the app later.

Comment: It is a NSArray, did log [response.responseDictionary class]; already

Comment: And Yes, I will email him ;)